# Bereak single line code into multiple lines in QTP

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

_ works to split a long line into multiple line in VBSCript. Wondering if it works for QTP as well

Comment: I don't know UFT but if it uses vbscript then it supports vbscript line continuation. It takes 2 minutes to add vbscript macros to any script/program (so a jscript/vbscript can host a vbscript/jscript macro language). In Windows Internet Explorer and Windows Scripting Host host vbscript and they, and any other program hosting vbscript, use c:\windows\system32\vbscript.dll to implement the language. Line continuation is part of the VBA standard that VBScript is based on. It's not optional.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the answer could be easily [found on google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qtp%20line%20continuation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use & _ for break your long lines.

```
sString = "Something very long " & _
                     "More on that" & _
                          "A little more"
```

Reference is [here](http://www.advancedqtp.com/old_forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2906)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13766523)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Next time, I will be very much careful.